# how to upgrade a spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

how to upgrade a spring boot application

Answer (score 1):

In the session management (you can do it on server level, which will be the default for all applications, or on application level, which will be for that app only), you can change default timeout, or even set 'No timeout' to disable it completely.

I'd not advise to completely disable, as old sessions will be gathering and storing in heap, which will result in OOM error at some point. So set it to something quite long, e.g. 8 hours. Also I'd recommend to set it only on application that it is really needed, not on server level for all apps.

Similarly in Global Security > LTPA, you can increase LTPA timeout to similar value.
Actually if users are using SPNEGO, they should be seamlessly reauthenticated when LTPA expires, but I dont know how your app will behave in that case.

In general, long timeouts are not recommended as they are using resources without a need and it is very inefficient. Application users should not relay on the session lasting forever.

Comment: @Rao Well, you need to test. If you have separate dev/test env, then you can set LTPA timeout to  something short, like 5 min, and session timeout to longer one and test how it will behave when LTPA expires. Regarding second part - 4 hours could be a good start. Change the settings and observe how the system behaves. You should watch JVM Heap, and Session counters for example via PMI.

Comment: @Rao how do you know that session is not invalidated? You could wrote a simple servlet to check if `request.getSession(false)` will return `null`, that would mean that session was removed.

Comment: @Rao, if you are using SPNEGO, there is no login, it is done automatically, so you can only see that session expired checking its data, like stored attributes, or evaluate `session.isNew()` method. What do you mean by 'browser isnt timing out'?? It wont close automatically.

Comment: You have to use `FORM` login, if you use `BASIC` and browser popup, credentials are stored in the headers and automatically resent when needed, so you cannot logged out, you would have to close the browser.

Comment: @Rao Its hard to tell as I dont know your application, technology it is using, your log in configuration and processing etc... If you use basic authentication, you should be asked only once to provide login details, dont know why it asks two times, maybe it redirects to different site. So I'm sorry but cant help you in there. You may enable security tracing to further investigate behavior of your app if needed.

Comment: @Rao, IHS must be correctly configured with WebSphere plugin to correctly route requests to the server holding session data. No any other additional role. And yes, if you set LTPA and session timeout to 4h, then session will be stored for 4h without activity. But if you close the browser, of course your session will be lost.